# Period map on non-Kähler manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, hodge-theory

Is there a theory of period map on non-Kähler manifolds that has Hodge decomposition? Any reference is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: So I guess one way to parse this is if $f:X\to B$ is a proper holomorphic submersion with connected fibers, and the Frölicher spectral sequence degenerates for all fibers, is the induced map to the period domain holomorphic? I expect the answer is no.

Comment: @user145520 Thank you for your comment. Is there any intuition or some ideas for you to believe it is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked Angella's book on non-Kähler geometry? He did some research on $\partial\bar\partial$ manifolds maybe provide some information which you need.